# HEROKU cannot read property query of null

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have an error with Heroku while i try to submit information on my app.
i'm following steps from the documentation : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/project/quickstart-heroku-connect/qs-heroku-connect-4

I run the server, i clic on submit button then on my term i get :

```
{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.228.214.47:5432]
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '54.228.214.47',
  port: 5432 }
/home/f.freitag/workspace/radiant-dusk-13720/server.js:17
        conn.query(

TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null
    at /home/f.freitag/workspace/radiant-dusk-13720/server.js:17:13
    at /home/f.freitag/workspace/radiant-dusk-13720/node_modules/pg/lib/pool.js:82:27
    at /home/f.freitag/workspace/radiant-dusk-13720/node_modules/pg/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:339:9
    at /home/f.freitag/workspace/radiant-dusk-13720/node_modules/pg/lib/pool.js:31:28
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/f.freitag/workspace/radiant-dusk-13720/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:176:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/f.freitag/workspace/radiant-dusk-13720/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:59:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)

npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/node/bin/node" "/usr/local/node/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! phone-change@0.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! Failed at the phone-change@0.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phone-change package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs phone-change
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phone-change
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried to see on google for this problem but i found nothing. Also, i'm not a nodeJS programmer, it's maybe simple.
I didn't change code from the git clone.

Here the code from server.js. I put a comment on the line error

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var pg = require('pg');
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/update', function(req, res) {
    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function (err, conn, done) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        conn.query( //the error
            'UPDATE salesforce.Contact SET Phone = $1, HomePhone = $1,  MobilePhone = $1 WHERE LOWER(FirstName) = LOWER($2) AND LOWER(LastName) = LOWER($3) AND LOWER(Email) = LOWER($4)',
            [req.body.phone.trim(), req.body.firstName.trim(), req.body.lastName.trim(), req.body.email.trim()],
            function(err, result) {
                    done();
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(400).json({error: err.message});
                    }
                    else {
                        res.json(result);
                    }
                  });
                }
            else {
                done();
                res.json(result);
            }
        }
    );
});
app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Done, need something else ? another file ?  As i said, i didn't change the code exept 'HomePhone = $1'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Heroku Connect mappings. Since you've added a new field in the query you also need to update the mappings which you did during the initial setup of Heroku Connect for `Contact` object.

Steps:

1. Go to Heroku Connect
2. Visit mappings section and select the mapping for `Contact`.
3. Click on Edit and select `HomePhone` and save it.

Once above steps are done rerun the application and now should see `HomePhone` field value populated as same as `Phone`.